# can I make two buttons to show up page in Elementor pro

Tags: wordpress, web, button, frontend, elementor

good day,

I am using Wordpress and Elementor Pro for creating my website but I want to do like photo attached but I could not

I search a lot and found some said two buttons or nav menu or hamburger panel
but I didn't find any of these

So how can I make like this once user choose button shows up something else?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtVLu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "Tabs"? You can place her different contents at the same area by clicking the Tab Title which you could style with css.